# Need help figuring out why a JavaScript button onclick is not working

Tags: javascript

I have a Sharepoint2010 site and am trying to execute a Javascript code to create some drop down selection menus with a GO button at the end. The GO button is supposed to run a function that does a URL redirect via the window.location command based on the choices in the dropdown. I have this saved in a TXT file then called within a CEWP.

The snippet of code that I believe is having issues is with the function or the button itself.

This is what I have at the moment in a simplified form:

```
function submitGo(){
window.location = "www.google.com"
}
<button onclick="submitGo()">Go</button>
```

But when I load my page and click the GO button it just reloads my sharepoint page and does not perform the redirect. I have tried replacing the function in the  command with the window.location command directly and it does the same thing. I am at a complete loss as to why this is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell why this is happening. It could be browser-specific. We could try to prevent a post-back by including **return false;** at the end of your onclick function:

```
<button onclick="submitGo(); return false;">Go</button>
```

**Update:**
also, you might need to set button's type explicitly:

```
<button type="button" onclick="submitGo(); return false;">Go</button>
```

Comment: Adding the return and the type together in the button command solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

`window.location = "http://www.google.com"`;

You should also learn to take advantage of the web developer tools for javascript debugging.  For example, in IE, press F12.  If you then click the 'Console' tab, you have a REPL console where you can interactively enter javascript in the context of the current page.  For example, you can type....

```
alert("Hello World")
```

.....and it will execute that command.   Extending that example, you can type....

```
 window.location = "www.google.com"
```

..... and see that it doesnt' work.

Using this interactive console to fine-tune jQuery selectors saves me TONS of time.