# SharePoint App auto refreshes when using <button> control

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, html

I am creating a Sharepoint 2013 app which perform some task on a button click. When i use the  control, the app page auto refreshes after few seconds after the click.

```
<button id="loadButton" title="loadButton" value="loadButton"></button>
```

But when i use a button control with input type, it works correctly.

```
<input type="button" id="loadButton" value="LoadButton"/>
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: are you doing this in an aspx-Page?

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent the `<button>` from performing POST, all we have to do is to add `type='button'`

Correct:

```
<button type="button" id="loadButton" title="loadButton" value="loadButton"></button>
```

Wrong:

```
<button id="loadButton" title="loadButton" value="loadButton"></button>
```

This question is essentially the same as [this one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88987/need-help-figuring-out-why-a-javascript-button-onclick-is-not-working/88989#88989).

Answer (score 0):

your missing the id in the button.

**html**

```
<button title="loadButton" value="loadButton"></button>
```

should be:

```
<button id="loadButton" title="loadButton" value="loadButton"></button>
```

html button control needs an id!

**JS**

```
function sharePointReady() {
    ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    $("#loadButton").click(function (event) {
        refreshpage();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    callme();
}

function callme() {
    //call after button event do your stuff!
}

function refreshpage() {
    // button clicked do your stuff!

    //return nothing! no postback occures!
    return false;
}
```

html button has builtin auto postback which i think uses submit event. where input needs to be explicitly told to do postback especially when using button in input so does nothing like in your case!

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. I have edited my question.

Comment: do you not want it to refresh? what is the button doing and what is the input doing correctly that the button is not?

Comment: On button click, text inside <p> changes. But after few second the page auto refreshes if i use the first control. Auto refresh should not happen.

Comment: ahh i get you so you dont want postback!

Comment: in your button event i presume its js just return false!

Comment: just updated my answer to show you what i mean!